# RPostgres on Mac fails to connect to Amazon RDS Aurora database

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-aurora, rpostgresql, rpostgres

I am facing an awkward issue connecting to a Postgres database deployed on AWS Aurora. Connection attempts from R on Mac OS, using the DBI and RPostgres frameworks are rejected with the message:

```
 Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

The connection is made through:

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
  dbname = 'xxx',
  host = 'xxx',
  port = 5432,
  user = 'xxx',
  password = 'xxx')
```

Troubleshooting this issue revealed the following - all systems are running the same version of R (4.0.4), DBI (1.1.1), RPostgres (1.3.2) and Rcpp (1.0.6):

- running the connection from a centos7 distribution works fine
- running the connection from windows 10 works fine
- **running the connection with RPostgres from osx 10.15.7 fails**
- running the connection with RPostgresSQL from osx 10.15.7 succeeds
- connecting through Python client (sql alchemy) succeeds
- netcat confirms successful connection from osx 10.15.7

Unfortunately, I cannot afford to move to RPostgresSQL and I need to solve the problem currently experienced with RPostgres on Mac connecting to Amazon RDS.

Other useful information:

- the same database I am trying to access on Arora is accessible on a Centos7 distribution with no issues
- the only difference between the two DB instances seems to be the encoding: SHOW SERVER_ENCODING returns SQL_ASCII on the Centos instance and UTF8 on the aurora cluster. As far as I understand though, RPostgres forces UTF8 and my local environment on the Mac is also set to UTF8.

I am no expert in DB administration and would tremendously appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.